# How to style text by a specific index?

Tags: html, css

I need to be able to bold text in an element(it doesn't need to work with pre, but i'd prefer it would).

for example:

This is **the** string i wish to display.

is there an ability to do that purely in html and css with indexes if yes then how can i do that? or should i use something else?

Edit: The text is dynamic. where to bold will be specified with *

Comment: Just wrap the bold word with an element and modify its style by CSS

Comment: i need it to be dynamic it much like stackoverflow does with *. do i do not know where the text will be bold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story short, from what I know there is no way with CSS only to select text by text. So you will need to use javascript to achieve what you are after.

You can use [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
// check all elments with given class
[...document.querySelectorAll('.check-those-p-tags')].forEach(function(element){
  // iterate over all elements
  var resultString = element.innerHTML.replace(
    /the/g, // search for all (g = global) "the" in the innerHTML
    '<span class="alert">$&</span>' // replace/wrap the "the" with some tags and class
    // "$&" means => Inserts the matched substring.
  );
  element.innerHTML = resultString; // overwrite the innerHTML with the new string
});
```

```css
.alert { color: red; font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<p class="check-those-p-tags">This is the string i wish to display.</p>
```

You can also write it almost in one line

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.check-those-p-tags')].forEach(function(element){
  element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/the/g, '<span class="alert">$&</span>');
});
```

```css
.alert { color: red; font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<p class="check-those-p-tags">This is the string i wish to display.</p>
```